# Unable to Install Any Libraries Using pip in Python 3.5.2 Environment on Windows 11

Tags: python, installation, pip

Hello Stack Overflow Community.

I am currently working with a project cloned from GitHub which requires Python 3.5.2, Keras 2.1.5 and TensorFlow 1.6.0. I'm running this on a Windows 11 machine. To accommodate this, I've created a new Python 3.5.2 environment and activated it.

However, when I try to install any library using pip, the operation does not complete. Whether it's Keras, TensorFlow, or any other package, the console responds with "Collecting [package_name]" but doesn't seem to download or install the library.

For instance, when I run these commands:
pip install keras==2.1.5
pip install tensorflow==1.6.0

The console outputs "Collecting keras==2.1.5" and "Collecting tensorflow==1.6.0", but there are no further updates, and the packages don't get installed.

I've tried searching for similar issues and have attempted to reinstall pip in this environment, but so far, no solution seems to work.

Could anyone help me understand what's going wrong and how I might resolve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you running Python? From the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`python -m pip install SomePackage==1.0.4`    # specific version

When using `-m pip`, you are telling Python to run pip as the main module. Python likely is not recognizing pip as what you want it to run, since it is not a command-line operation.

Comment: While I agree this is a likely solution, you might want to explain why doing this rather then just pip might solve the issue since "code only" answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks, I got distracted and didn't actually provide a solid answer.